# Extract RGB from JPEG image, using libjpeg C++ Library

Tags: c++, c++11, libjpeg

I am using the libjpeg library to read and copy a jpeg into an editing program that I am writing in C++

I have a display buffer which is a vector of a datatype called ColorData

All ColorData consists of is 3 floats (RGB)

Here is my code that opens the jpeg files

```
PixelBuffer * IOManager::load_jpg_to_pixel_buffer(const char *file_name){
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

  FILE * infile;

  JSAMPARRAY buffer;

  if ((infile = fopen(file_name, "rb")) == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Could not open the jpg file: " << file_name << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr; 

  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

  jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
  jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
  jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

  int width = static_cast<int>(cinfo.output_width);

  int height = static_cast<int>(cinfo.output_height);

  std::cout << typeid(cinfo.colormap).name() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Width: " << width << "Height: " << height << std::endl;

  PixelBuffer * image_buffer = new PixelBuffer(width, height, ColorData());

  std::cout << cinfo.output_components << std::endl;

   buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)
    ((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components, 1);

  /* Step 6: while (scan lines remain to be read) */
  /*           jpeg_read_scanlines(...); */

  /* Here we use the library's state variable cinfo.output_scanline as the
   * loop counter, so that we don't have to keep track ourselves.
   */
  while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
    /* jpeg_read_scanlines expects an array of pointers to scanlines.
     * Here the array is only one element long, but you could ask for
     * more than one scanline at a time if that's more convenient.
     */
    (void) jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    /* Assume put_scanline_someplace wants a pointer and sample count. */

  }

  return nullptr;


}
```

How can I get the RGB value from the jpeg using the libjpeg?

Comment: JPEG files are [YCbCr encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion), possibly with [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). You'll have to either write the necessary color conversion code, or use a library that can do it for you.

Comment: @Cornstalks, libjpeg has ready-made conversions built-in, you just need to specify proper 'out_color_space'

Comment: @Dmitry: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

The RGB values are in `buffer`. It's actually an array of arrays, so you have to index `buffer[0]`.

Something like this:

```
while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height)
{
    (void) jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);

    // get the pointer to the row:
    unsigned char* pixel_row = (unsigned char*)(buffer[0]);
    // iterate over the pixels:
    for(int i = 0; i < cinfo.output_width; i++)
    {
        // convert the RGB values to a float in the range 0 - 1
        float red = (float)(*pixel_row++) / 255.0f;
        float green = (float)(*pixel_row++) / 255.0f;
        float blue = (float)(*pixel_row++) / 255.0f;
    }
}
```

This is assuming `cinfo.output_components` is 3.